# docker invalid reference format

Tags: docker, docker-compose

> my files strucutre . i have i am building two container one is mysql database 
>    another is python  application

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  mysql-dev:

    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: vlearn

    ports:
      - "3308:3308"

  app:

    image: ./app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

### app file

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile


CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

> When i Run docker-compose up
>   i get following
>
> ### Error
>
> Pulling app (./app:)...
>
> ERROR: invalid reference format

### my directory structure

```
├── app
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Pipfile
│   └── Pipfile.lock
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: What’s your directory structure?

Comment: i have added to question please check it

Comment: I think the work directory should be "WORKDIR /app"

Comment: Should it not be build: “./app” instead of image?

Comment: thanks that works . could you answer in answer section so other can see clear answer. so kind of you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 app:

    build : ./app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

> it must be  **build : ./app**  instead of  image: ./app